# _CastError (type '() => Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast) I No knowledge of Map<String, dynamic>

Tags: flutter, dart

> > wrong here /* Cal.frommap(documentSnapshot.data as Map<String,dynamic>)) */
> > I want to fetch data from firebase into pie chart.

The first part is a widget to retrieve data from firebase. but i wonder Cal.frommap(documentSnapshot.data as Map<String,dynamic>)) I'm doing something wrong, it doesn't run.

```
Widget bulidChart(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("chart").snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return LinearProgressIndicator();
          } else {
            
            List<Cal> cal = snapshot.data!.docs
                .map((documentSnapshot) =>
                    Cal.frommap(documentSnapshot.data as Map<String,dynamic>))
                .toList();

            return _buildChart(context, cal);
          }
        });
  }
```

This section shows the pie chart as an example.

```
  Widget _buildChart(BuildContext context, List<Cal> cal) {
    KcalData = cal;
    _generateData(KcalData);
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Container(
        child: Center(
            child: Column(
          children: [
            charts.PieChart(
              datachart!,
              animate: true,
              
              behaviors: [
                charts.DatumLegend(
                    entryTextStyle: charts.TextStyleSpec(
                        color: charts.MaterialPalette.purple.shadeDefault,
                        fontSize: 20,
                        fontFamily: 'Mitr'))
              ],
            )
          ],
        )),
      ),
    );
}
```

```
class Cal{
  String? foodName;
  double? kCal;
  String? colorVal;
  Cal(this.foodName,this.kCal,this.colorVal);
  
  Cal.frommap(Map<String,dynamic>map)
  :assert(map['foodName']!=null),
   assert(map['kCal']!=null),
   assert(map['colorVal']!=null),
  foodName=map['foodName'],
  kCal=map['kCal'],
  colorVal=map['colorVal'];


  String toString()=> "Record<$foodName:$kCal:$colorVal>";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is saying that what your are getting from `documentSnapshot.data` is a function which is returning `Map<String, dynamic>`. But you had casted it as simply `Map<String, dynamic>`.

To understand this, I suggest you read the following [example](https://flutteragency.com/how-to-get-all-data-from-a-firestore-collection-in-flutter/#:%7E:text=Using%20StreamBuilder%20as%20shown%20below%3A), and read carefully this method in example `getExpenseItems` which is showing proper way to extract the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Cal.frommap(documentSnapshot.data as Map<String,dynamic>)
```

remove the casting and put () after data so it will be:

```
 Cal.frommap(documentSnapshot.data())
```

because data() will return a map